# How do I Display a .svg Icon Without it Getting Clipped?

Tags: html, css, image, svg, vector-graphics

I am trying to display [these](https://scotthsmith.com/projects/social-icons/) social media icons on my website in such a way that I can change the color using css (so i can add the hover effect shown in the code below).

However, since these are vector image files (`.svg`) I couldn't seem to find a way to insert the image into my web page using the conventional `<img src="">` method. So I proceeded to create CSS classes to get the image to appear as a CSS mask (thus allowing me to change the color via CSS).

However, I quickly noticed that the sides of the otherwise circular vector graphic icons were slightly cutoff. Being the perfectionist that I am, I wanted to make the icons actually appear round as they were supposed to. So, after checking out the [`webkit-mask` MSDN entry](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-mask) I increased the width of the `.media-buttons` class and used `-webkit-mask-position` to shift the image a few pixels down and to the left as is evident in my code below. This obviously did not work.

It has also come to my attention that `-webkit-mask` is not fully supported by all browsers.

CSS:

```
#cross{-webkit-mask: url("http://path/to/image.svg") no-repeat;}
.media-buttons {
    width: 202px;
    height: 202px;
    background: #000;
    -webkit-mask-position: 10px 10px;
}
.media-buttons:hover {background: rgb(94, 176, 201);}
```

HTML:

```
<img class="media-buttons" id="cross">
```

**TL;DR**, I am looking for a (possibly new) way to display my `.svg` icons that has somewhat decent browser support and the ability to manipulate the icon's color via CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way:

```css
svg:hover {
  color: #009BCD;
}

p {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<svg width="200px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 200 200" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:sketch="http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/ns" display="none">
    <title>Cross</title>
    <description>Created with Sketch (http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch)</description>
    <defs></defs>
    <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" sketch:type="MSPage">
        <path d="M100,0 C44.771524,3.03201907e-14 0,44.771524 0,100 C0,155.228476 44.771524,200 100,200 C155.228476,200 200,155.228476 200,100 C200,44.771524 155.228476,-3.41060513e-14 100,0 Z M84.0763011,40 L115.923699,40 L115.923699,84.1405714 L160,84.1405714 L160,116.034408 L115.923699,116.034408 L115.923699,160.16875 L84.0763011,160.16875 L84.0763011,116.034408 L40,116.034408 L40,84.1405714 L84.0763011,84.1405714 L84.0763011,40 Z" id="Cross" fill="currentColor" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup"></path>
    </g>
</svg>



<p>
Heh! What's this
<svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
  <use xlink:href="#Cross"/>
</svg>
doing in the middle of a sentence?
</p>

<svg width="50px" height="50px" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
  <use xlink:href="#Cross"/>
</svg>
```

What I did here was:

- Copy the SVG into the HTML (and removed the XML preamble)
- Set `display="none"` on the `<svg>` so that it is invisible on the page.
- Changed the `fill` on the icons `<path>` element to `currentColor`

Now every time you want a copy of the icon to appear, create a mini-svg that reverences the `<path>` in the first SVG.

```
<svg width="50px" height="50px" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
  <use xlink:href="#Cross"/>
</svg>
```

Just set it's size with the `width` and `height` values. You just need to include each icon once and you can reference them as many times as you like.

**What is currentColor for?**

`currentColor` is a special color value in SVGs that tells the elements to use the value of the current `color` setting.  It means you can set the color outside the `<use>` element and it gets inherited by whatever the `<use>` is referencing.  Normally you can't style each of the icon references individually. They would all be stuck having whatever `fill` the original `<path>` is set to.

**Using just the original SVG**

```css
svg path {
  fill: blue;
}

svg:hover path {
  fill: #009BCD;
}
```

```html
<p>SVG just used as is</p>

<svg width="100px" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 200 200" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:sketch="http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/ns">
    <title>Cross</title>
    <description>Created with Sketch (http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch)</description>
    <defs></defs>
    <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill-rule="evenodd" sketch:type="MSPage">
        <path d="M100,0 C44.771524,3.03201907e-14 0,44.771524 0,100 C0,155.228476 44.771524,200 100,200 C155.228476,200 200,155.228476 200,100 C200,44.771524 155.228476,-3.41060513e-14 100,0 Z M84.0763011,40 L115.923699,40 L115.923699,84.1405714 L160,84.1405714 L160,116.034408 L115.923699,116.034408 L115.923699,160.16875 L84.0763011,160.16875 L84.0763011,116.034408 L40,116.034408 L40,84.1405714 L84.0763011,84.1405714 L84.0763011,40 Z" id="Cross" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup"></path>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Never thought of that! Is there a way that I can just use the original instance of the image while still being able to change color?

Comment: I've added an additional example where I just use the original SVG inline.

Comment: Would there be any side effects to removing `version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:sketch="http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/ns"` from the `svg` tag along with the title, description and defs tags?

Comment: No. It is safe to remove all those as long as you are inlining the SVG in your HTML.

Comment: the example with the original svg is still a little clipped... do I just make the width/height bigger?

Comment: I'm guessing you are viewing in FF?  It looks fine in Chrome.  FF seems to be a little off with its rendering atm.  If it's bothering you, just make the viewBox a little bigger so that it renders slightly smaller.  For example `viewBox="-1 -1 202 202"`.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell for sure where this bug is coming from but I think it has something to do with borders. Add a 1px border and you'll see some really weird behaviour. Now to answer your question: To make sure your image doesn't get clipped you can use `mask-size`. E.g. `-webkit-mask-size: 50% 50%;`

Just don't think masks are ready for primetime just yet.

Here's a pen that demonstrates this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ONLRbZ